# Websql can not drop and create table after worklight direct update

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, web-sql

We are building hybrid applications with worklight framework 6.1.0.2 20141016-1539.
In the wlCommonInit method of main.js, we setup table schema with code like this:

```
db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 10 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {  
            ....
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CAR_OFFLINE_DATA (COMPANY_CODE TEXT, SLIP_NO TEXT, DELIVERY_AREA_CODE TEXT, DELIVERY_DATE TEXT, DELIVERY_ATTRIBUTE TEXT, DELIVERY_TYPE_CODE TEXT, CAR_CODE TEXT, CREATETIME DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,UPDATETIME DATE)");
            ....
    },dao.db_error);
```

In order to meet our new requirement in the next patch, our data model have to change.
So we create new table to replace CAR_OFFLINE_DATA table which used for the same purpose.
Then we will patch application with worklight direct update.

This is what we have done in the next patch.
We drop the table in previous version, and create a table with similar name except that it has additional columns:

```
db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 10 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {  
        tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CAR_OFFLINE_DATA");//SQL 1 rebuild this table
            ....
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CAR_OFFLINE_DATA_V2 (SEQID integer primary key autoincrement ,COMPANY_CODE TEXT, SLIP_NO TEXT, DELIVERY_AREA_CODE TEXT, DELIVERY_DATE TEXT, DELIVERY_ATTRIBUTE TEXT, DELIVERY_TYPE_CODE TEXT, CAR_CODE TEXT, CREATETIME DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,UPDATETIME DATE)");
        //SQL 2
            ....
    },dao.db_error);
},
```

After we direct update application , strange things happened.
Debug tools of desktop safari and chrome shows that table CAR_OFFLINE_DATA didn't drop by web sql and CAR_OFFLINE_DATA_V2 does not exists either.
Any sql execution related to CAR_OFFLINE_DATA_V2 such us below all failed with warnings that they can't prepare statement with table which is not exist.
But if we attach success callback function for each sql execution, then these function definitely will be invoke every time when we start application.

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
        var sql = "DELETE FROM CAR_OFFLINE_DATA_V2 WHERE CREATETIME < datetime('now','-2 day')";
        tx.executeSql(sql);
    },dao.db_error);
```

I am wondering why can't we drop and create web sql table in application after worklight direct update?
Is it because of mechanism of direct update? Or simply because of some issue related to websql?

Any suggestion or comment is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Did you verify that this code works w/out Direct Update? That is, install app > Use app > **Install** updated app >> Verify table was dropped and new table created.

Comment: Also, which environment are you testing this in? iOS Simulator? Android Emulator?

Comment: Yes, this problem only happens after direct update. If we patch the latest version to user with new packaged .ipa or .apk, then every thing will be fine, but our boss doesn't like to distribute updates with this way.
We test this app in iphone 5S actual device, zenfone 5 and android simulator but they all failed.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I am trying to isolate the issue... Can you provide a test case application that manages to reproduce this so we could debug it?

Comment: Ok, I will try to help you isolate this issue in our tightly coupled app. This problem happens even if we exit application, remove it in background then restart it after direct update.

Comment: You should be able to create an app with just the websql to see if it reproduces or not.

Comment: This issue has been resolve. We found out that it was syntax error that cause web-sql transaction failure, which rollback the sql that alter table schema.

Comment: Great - could you please write this as an answer to the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error was eventually concluded to be not Worklight-related.

> We found out that it was syntax error that cause web-sql transaction
>   failure, which rollback the sql that alter table schema.